# Find the image of an element without clear function rule.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

How can I find $f(4)$ from the following equation:

$$f(x) + f(2x+1) = 6x+10$$

Comment: Maybe, solve $x=2x+1$ to get one concrete value. Hmm, maybe not so helpful :-(.

Comment: is it given that $f(x)$ is a polynomial?

Comment: No, there are no more additional info.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

$f(x)=2x+4$ satisfies the equation so $f(4)=12$

Comment: Perfect, thanks, could you please explain how you find this rule?

Comment: Umm, why is $f$ necessarily affine?

Comment: This means we can't claim $f(4)$ *doesn't* equal $12$ but this is no reason at all to claim that $f(4)$ must equal $12$.  I can't see any reason to assume $f(x)=2x+4$ is the *only* possible function that satisfies the equation.

Comment: According to Husam there is no additional information given. This means that we have to assume that there are **different** functions $f(x)$ that satisfy the equation $f(x)+f(2x+1)=6x+10$ with different values of $f(4)$ until the opposite is proven.

Comment: You are right @MartinRosenau, this problem founded in grade 12 book, so we can't use complicated methods to solve it.

Comment: @Husam However, this could already be "additional information". I don't know how students in the 12th grade define the word "function". However, if they do it like we did, the answer to your question is: The information given is not enough to calculate the value of $f(4)$ because there are different functions $f(x)$ that satisfy the equation $f(x)+f(2x+1)=6x+10$.

Comment: @Husam Just to make that point a bit more clear: Assume a 7th grade book asks: "There is a number $x$ and it is only known that $x^3-3x^2+2x=0$, what is $5x+4$?". Would it be a valid answer to say: "$x=1$ satisfies the equation, so $5x+4=9$"? (although $x=2$ and $x=0$ would also be possible)

Comment: You are right @Martin.

Answer (score 12):

Let $g(x)=f(x)-2x-4$ to get

$$g(x)+g(2x+1)=0$$

Substitute $x\mapsto2^x-1$ and let $h(x)=g(2^x-1)$ to get

$$h(x)+h(x+1)=0$$

We can produce infinitely many solutions for $h$. An obvious form can be given by trigonometric functions, and more generally Fourier series. As a simple example:

$$h(x)=A\sin(\pi x)$$

$$g(x)=A\sin(\pi\log_2(x+1))$$

$$f(x)=2x+4+A\sin(\pi\log_2(x+1))$$

$$f(4)=12+A\sin(\pi\log_2(5))$$

which depends on the arbitrary value $A$. Thus there is no unique solution, given the conditions.

Comment: +1: Nice. ${}{}$

Comment: Excuse me for this request. I have not understood the 3th row starting from Substitute to get $h(x)+h(x+1)=0$. However my sincere compliments.

Comment: @Sebastiano Perhaps it's clearer now. Plug in $2^x-1$ for $x$ and simplify.

Comment: It might be worth being explicit how one produces infinite many solutions: you define $h$ to be whatever you want in $[0,1)$ then define $h(x+n)=(-1)^n\cdot h(x)$ where $x\in [0,1)$ and $n\in \mathbb Z$ - you don't even have to know what a trigonometric function is!

Comment: @MiloBrandt The provided example already provides infinitely many solutions, but sure you can do that instead.